# Update Location in Mapview Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, cllocationmanager

In my current project.

I need user's location at every `50 meter` user move.

So Basically After open application every `50 meter` change I need user location for call web service in `Objective c`. Also i want same process run when application is in background state.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set your location track in

```
//create location manager object
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

//there will be a warning from this line of code
[locationManager setDelegate:self];

//and we want it to be as accurate as possible
//regardless of how much time/power it takes
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

//set the amount of metres travelled before location update is made
[locationManager setDistanceFilter:50];
```

and add

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]) {
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

**Update**

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
CLLocation *location = locations.lastObject;
NSLog(@"%@", location.description);

 //In here you get all details like

   NSLog(@"latitude = %@",location.coordinate.latitude);
   NSLog(@"longitude = %@",location.coordinate.longitude);
   NSLog(@"altitude = %@",location.altitude);
   NSLog(@"horizontalAccuracy = %@",location.horizontalAccuracy);
   NSLog(@"verticalAccuracy = %@",location.verticalAccuracy);
   NSLog(@"timestamp = %@",location.timestamp);
   NSLog(@"speed = %@",location.speed);
   NSLog(@"course = %@",location.course);

}
```

Comment: I set [locationManager setDistanceFilter:50];
in my code

Comment: But which method call when location is greater than 50 meter?

Comment: like every 50 meter change just open alert view with message "Your location change 50 m"

Comment: the delegate method is called - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);
}

Comment: It's Work. But one more question from  [locations lastObject] how i get latitude and longitude?

Comment: Great..Thanks @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: if same process of location update and web service calling is i want to when application is in background.Then what extra code i need in my project ?

Comment: Yes i do it ..any other thing i need to do?

Answer (score 2):

1. You have to make object of CLLocationManager when application starts and set it's delegate

Add the below code to get user's current location

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

2. Now add the delegate of CLLocationManagaer that is didUpdateToLocation and add the following code in that.

   **CLLocationDistance meters = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:oldLocation];**

   ```
   if(meters==50)
   {
       // CALL YOU WEBSERVICE
   }
   ```